# No me agarra la info de un API REST en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

He estado siguiendo un tutorial para consumir una API REST de Pokemon en Angular. Por ahora solo se escribe el nombre del Pokemon y al dar Click, dentro de la consola debe traer los datos del PokeApi, sin embargo no lo esta haciendo y en verdad no se que puede ser el error porque no me tira nada.
El HTML es el siguiente

```
<p>Nombre de Pokemon: </p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<button click="search()" >Buscar </button>
```

El TS es el siguiente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokemonService } from '../servicio/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon',
  templateUrl: './pokemon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon.component.css']
})
export class PokemonComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService) {
    this.name = "";
  } //como injectar dependencias

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  search(){
    this.pokemonService.getPokemon(this.name).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

En cualquier caso dentro del app.module.ts ya esta agregado el HTTPClient y FormsModule.
Gracias y si necesitan otra parte del codigo, con todo gusto se las paso c:

Comment: A lo que haces click en el botón buscar,  en el console.log(data) no te devuelve nada?

Comment: No, ni un error ni nada, por eso me extraña

Comment: Y en el servicio,? Llámalo en el constructor y ve si te devuelve algo, sino te devuelve debe estar algo mal en el servicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui lo que te falta son dos cosas, mandar la variable a la vista, y asignar tu respuesta, lo que imprime la consola, a esa variable, te lo expongo...

```
<p>Nombre de Pokemon: {{ name }}</p><!-- las llaves se usan para llamar variables-->
```

Solamente con agregar eso, ya hacemos referencia a una variable en tu `.ts` ahora debes asignar tu variable `name` al resultado que te devuelve tu API

```
  search(){
    this.pokemonService.getPokemon(this.name).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.name = data;//Con esto asignamos la variable
    })
  }
```

Automaticamente el valor será actualizado en tu `.html`. Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos!!